# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Tags: php, html

Soy nuevo en php y en el crud que hago de una tabla con los datos codigo, titulo y nota cuando hago el editar me aparece este error: **Parse error: "syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\editar.php on line 29**, y ya he intentado corregirlo pero no encontré la manera al no tener suficiente conocimiento.

si es necesario algo mas lo puedo agregar y muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Este es el código que tengo:
index.php

```
<?php 
    require_once "conexion.php";
    require_once "metodosCrud.php";

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>crud</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="procesos/insertar.php" method="post">
    <label>Titulo</label>
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" name="txttitulo">
    <p></p>
    <label for="nota" name="nota">Nota</label>
<select name="nota" id="nota" >
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
    <p></p>
    <button>Agregar</button>
</form>

<br><br>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Titulo</td>
        <td>Nota</td>
        <td>Actualizar</td>
        <td>Eliminar</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $obj= new metodos();
    $sql="SELECT codigo,titulo,nota from series ORDER BY nota ASC";
    $datos=$obj->mostrarDatos($sql);

    foreach ($datos as $key ) {
 ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key['titulo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['nota']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $key['codigo'] ?>">
            Editar
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="procesos/eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $key['codigo'] ?>">
            eliminar
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    }
 ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

y donde lo edito (editar.php):

```
<?php 

    require_once "conexion.php";
    $obj= new conectar();
    $conexion=$obj->conexion();
    $codigo=$_GET['codigo'];
    $sql="SELECT titulo,nota 
            from series where codigo='$codigo'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    $ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="procesos/actualizar.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" hidden="" value="<?php echo $codigo ?>" name="id">
    <label>Titulo</label>
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" name="txttitulo" value="<?php echo $ver[0] ?>">
    <p></p>
    <label>Nota</label>
    <p></p>
    <select name="nota" id="nota" type="int" value="<?= echo $ver[1] ?>">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
    
    <p></p>
    <button>Agregar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

La linea del error es:

```
<select name="nota" id="nota" type="int" value="<?= echo $ver[1] ?>">
```

si es nesesario tambien incluyo la conexion.php, metodosCrud.php y como tengo la base de datos, en ese orden:

```
<?php 

    class conectar{
        private $servidor="localhost";
        private $usuario="root";
        private $bd="series";
        private $password="";

        public function conexion(){
            $conexion=mysqli_connect($this->servidor,
                                     $this->usuario,
                                     $this->password,
                                     $this->bd);
            return $conexion;
        }

    }




    
 ?>
```

```
<?php 

    class metodos{
        public function mostrarDatos($sql){
            $c= new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();

            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

            return mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
        public function insertarDatosTitulo($datos){
            $c= new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();

            $sql="INSERT into series (titulo,nota)
                            values ('$datos[0]','$datos[1]')";

            return $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        }

        public function actualizaDatosTitulo($datos){
            $c= new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();

            $sql="UPDATE series set titulo='$datos[0]',
                                        nota='$datos[1]'
                                where codigo='$datos[2]'";
            return $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        }
        public function eliminarDatosTitulo($codigo){
            $c= new conectar();
            $conexion=$c->conexion();
            $sql="DELETE from series where codigo='$codigo'";
            return $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        }
    }
 ?>
```

```
create database series;
use series;


CREATE TABLE `series` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nota` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Creo que con bastante menos código, pero **indicando cual es la línea 29**, habría sido mas que suficiente. Te sugiero que consultes lo que es un [mcve], y que te pases por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He programdo algo con PHP pero nunca he visto que se pudiera empezar por <?= que en JSP es parecido con <%= ¿Puede ser una confunción entre lenguajes?

El error que muestras se debería cambiar el código por el siguiente

```
<select name="nota" id="nota" type="int" value="<?php echo $ver[1] ?>">
```

que es como lo estas haciendo en los demás inputs.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias creo que fue eso el problema pero ahora me dice otro error, si me puedes ayudar con este también te lo agradecería aun más. Undefined index: codigo in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\editar.php on line 6
 `$codigo=$_GET['codigo']; `

Comment: Te esta diciendo que el GET no encuentra la variale porque no llamas a la página con algo  como localhost\crud\editar.php?codigo=
Por GET visto que pasas la variable id en vinculos.
En los formularios estas usando el metodo POST, que es distinto al GET.  $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];